# On Sheets/Excel, when all the cell values below (eg) row 9 in column X shift down I want the cells in the same rows in column Y to also shift down?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Column X on Sheet B automatically gets all its values from Sheet A. The rest of the Sheet B table just has normal human entry cells. All the cells in Sheet A are human entry.

On Sheet A new values can be entered on any part of the sheet, not just the bottom, so new values in Sheet A don't always go to the bottom of column X in Sheet B - they go into the middle of column X, moving the below column X values down one cell each and throwing column X out of sync with the rest of the table.

I would like to know how, whenever there's a new value in Sheet A and so column X in Sheet B, there can automatically be a new row in the Sheet B table with the new value still going in Column X and the rest of the row blank, so that the Column Y cells move down too and hence the cells that were next to each other before can still stay next to each other.

EDIT: A detail: Column A values don't go directly into Column X, they go into Column W which is a few thousand cells long for all the relevant cells in Sheet A (about 500 cells from each of 8 relevant columns), then Column X is `=UNIQUE(SORT(W:W))`

EDIT 2: See a demo sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ohm4nukHKWei5UJ06uaUE2btaEDcWTqAFhDtdqy2YDo/edit?usp=sharing

Eg Say the Sheet B table looks like this

```
Column X:        Column Y:
Audi             Jibjab Jabjib
Honda            Woowoo
Mini             Chairrgr foo
Toyota           Frof Prog
```

If "Fiat" is added to the middle of Sheet A and so automatically goes in the middle of column X (whether column X is sorted or not new values would still go in the middle of the column), I would like the table to look like

```
Column X:        Column Y:
Audi             Jibjab Jabjib
Fiat
Honda            Woowoo
Mini             Chairrgr nfoo
Toyota           Frof Prog
```

Not like this! -:

```
Column X:        Column Y:
Audi             Jibjab Jabjib
Fiat             Woowoo
Honda            Chairrgr foo
Mini             Frof Prog
Toyota
```

How is this possible? Any way is acceptable, even if it involves some kind of script.

Thanks,
Milan

Comment: How do new values get added? By adding a full new row or by replacing an existing blank cell in column `X`? Also. How do you get the values from `Sheet A` to `Sheet B`. I mean what formula do you use?

Comment: @marikamitsos I've edited the description. Values get added by the human to Sheet A, the relevant bits are parts of columns G, K, N, Q, T and a few more columns, the human could add to any part of these columns (up to cell 500) at any time. These bits are then pulled into Column X in Sheet B with the first one X4 being ='SheetA'!G4 and the rest of the cells likewise, going down to G500 then X501 is ='SheetA'!K4 etc.

Comment: Try using `INDEX` or `INDIRECT` or a  `QUERY` formula. If still in need, please share a test sheet with some usable data and expected results.

Comment: Sorry I was trying keep it simple and missed a detail. Actually the values from Sheet A are pulled into Column W in Sheet B rather than Column X (in the same way described above though) and Column X that you see in the examples is =UNIQUE(SORT(W:W)), so that is why there are not loads of gaps in Column X.

Comment: Thanks though will try those formulas

Comment: You also mention *" ...G, K, N, Q, T and a few more columns, the human could add to any part of these columns (up to cell 500) at any time"* . I think this is getting  a long discussion. Please provide a test sheet as mentioned before. :/

Comment: Those are columns in Sheet A, arbitrary details about how the user adds to Sheet A. But sure I'll share something now

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ohm4nukHKWei5UJ06uaUE2btaEDcWTqAFhDtdqy2YDo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The second sheet is Sheet A and the third sheet is Sheet B

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. I believe your solution can be something very simple. Still. I don't see your expected results. I hate myself saying that, but I'm still lost in your sheet. One should not have to navigate through a labyrinth of data. Insulin dosages do confuse me. I think I ODed :)

Comment: I am also struggling to focus on the actual problem, when there is so much data.  Could you delete all of your current data (maybe in a new copy of your sheet), and replace it with simple values, like Apple, Orange, Lemon, or Audi, Fiat Honda, and then be clear which columns are human edited, and which are pulled driven by formulas?  And if the second sheet is Sheet A, as described in your question, please rename it to Sheet A.  Otherwise it is very confusing for us.  Then I'm pretty sure one of the experts here could come up with something to help you.  Thanks.  Just need a few rows of data..

Comment: Ah thanks :) I've just changed the sheet to match the @marikamitsos "share a test sheet" guide" sorry it was difficult to follow before, I've made it as clear as I can now. I'd recommend checking out Sheet B first, Sheet A is just the sheet where humans write words into.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ohm4nukHKWei5UJ06uaUE2btaEDcWTqAFhDtdqy2YDo/edit?usp=sharing it's still here

Comment: Thanks anyway @kirkg13, was wondering if you could explain how to implement an index?

Comment: Milan, by index, I meant yes, like in a book.  You would have a list of items in alphabetical order, and it could tell you what row each of those items was on, in another part of the sheet.  But that doesn't help solve the problem of the human-entered text getting misaligned, when new terms are entered.

Comment: For anyone reading this question, please see this excellent answer by expert Lance, over on the Google Support Community.  He explains as clearly as anything I've seen the issues with trying to link human entered data alongside computer generated data, eg results of a filter, or query, or sort....                                                                                      https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm03FmeqnDyQ9k/

Comment: His key paragraph in that answer is:                                                                                           There is no inherent link between dynamic data; meaning, data that is imported from another location and is likely to be re-ordered through sorting or insertion of rows, and static data; meaning, data that you hand-enter in a cell on a spreadsheet. The problem, as you've accurately described, is that imported data moves around, but the data entered locally does not.

Comment: Thank you Kirk. It looks like I'm screwed unless I move the whole thing off Excel to... somewhere else :)